# DropZone.js - Throwing an error on screen immediately after a file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js, and trying to figure out how can I throw an error BEFORE the file is shown in the dropzone UI.

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; 
     var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUpload", { url: "/myUrl/file", maxFiles: 1, maxFilesize: 2,
                    accept: function(file, done) {            
                                    var splitFileName = file.name.split(".");                    
                                    if (splitFileName[splitFileName.length - 1] != "bbb") {                                                                        
                                        done("Error! Files of this type are not accepted");                                    
                                    }
                                    else { done(); }
                                }                         
                    });
 myDropzone.options.acceptedFiles = '.bbb';
```

Suppose the user drags a file that is not with `.bbb` extension, then the file is still shown in the dropzone (with an 'X' sign).

Is it possible not to show that file in the dropzone, and even show a relevant error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out you can use the helpful `removeFile` method with `addedfile` event to easily achieve this kind of functionality.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
});
```

Inside this handler, you can remove files with `.bbb` extensions and set any kind of behavior you wish.